# Query to find out following

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have a users table and a friendships table
users(id, email, name)
friendships(id, user_id, friend_id, confirmed)

```
id   |  email  |  name
1    | xyz     | abc
2    | yui     | poi
3    | tar     | foo
4    | bar     | baz
```

In this if user with id 1 sends a friend request to user with id 2 then the row in friendship with look like

```
id               |  user_id   |  friend_id  | confirmed
1(generated key) |  1         |  2          | false
```

now when the user accepts the friends request

```
id               |  user_id   |  friend_id  | confirmed
1(generated key) |  1         |  2          | true
2                |  2         |  1          | true
```

So what I basically want to do is find out the users who are not friends with the current user, if user is already friends with the user or user has send a friend request then the resulting array of hash should not contain that value.

So in the above database the result array of hash should contain users with id 3 and 4.

So basically in the friendship table
user_id is the friend request sender id and the friend id is the receiver id

so wherever the user_id is the current_user it should not have the users corresponding to that friend_id and vise versa where the friend_id is current user it should not show the users with that corresponding user_id

I hope the question is clear enough to understand

Sorry for poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select u.* from users u 
where u.id not in ( select user_id id from friendship 
                    union 
                    select friend_id from friendship );
```

If you also want current user's record, add an `OR` clause with current user id.

```
select u.* from users u 
where u.id = ?
   OR u.id not in ( select user_id id from friendship 
                    union 
                    select friend_id from friendship );
```

Fill the parameter with current user id and execute.

Comment: the solution seems very simple and logical, but in this where can I check the above query just for the user who is currently logged in ?

Comment: No. You can't from this query. Because, you are expecting a list of users who are not in either of friendship user and friend ids. As someother user can be having current user's id in their friend id that too will be omitted. For current user's record to fetch, just add a `OR` clause to the above solution.